# How to feed custom post type to a facebook page?

Tags: custom-post-types, rss, facebook

I built my portfolio using custom post type. Later I created a Facebook page for my website under my FB account. Please advice how I can push from WP my work to FB.

- Image
- project description

No One of plugins helped me to push custom posts to FB page.

The plugins I tried:

- Facebook - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook/
- Facebook Page Publish -
  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-page-publish/
- WPBook

I followed the developers instructions. The plugins seems to work on WordPress side only.

Thanks in advance,
Marc

Comment: I tried all the plugins I was able to find. No luck.

Comment: Edit your question with the following information: A list of plugins (all link to their repos on wp.org) and the steps you tried. Then add a _detailed_ problem description of _what exactly didn't work_. Else no one will be able to help you, as your question is much too vague.

Comment: Do you want all your portfolio pages as status update on FB page with image and description ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

Wordbooker - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordbooker/
Custom post type integration - http://boring-group.com/blog/2011/02/23/wordpress-wordbooker-with-custom-post_types-solved/